# Symfony change service scope to prototype does not work on formtype services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I use forms as service (for my forms and for 'custom form types' as well).
In one of my form I have two fields which are two custom FormType

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('primary', 'shamp_searchable', [
            'class'  => '\Udg\CoreBundle\Entity\Ingredients\Ingredient',
            'source' => $this->router->generate('adminIngredient_search'),
        ])
        ->add('secondaries', 'shamp_searchable', [
            'class'    => '\Udg\CoreBundle\Entity\Ingredients\Ingredient',
            'source'   => $this->router->generate('adminIngredient_search'),
            'multiple' => true,
        ])
...
}
```

And I need the two instances of `shamp_searchable` form type to be different for some reason
So in my `service.yml` I change the scope to `prototype` as we can read in the doc

```
shamp.form.shamp_searchable_:
    class: Shamp\CoreBundle\Form\Type\SearchableOneToManyType
    scope: prototype
    arguments:
        - @shamp.form.shamp_searchable_onetomany.data_transformer
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: shamp_searchable }

shamp.form.shamp_searchable.data_transformer:
    class: Shamp\CoreBundle\Form\DataTransformer\SearchableOneToManyDataTransformer
    scope: prototype
    arguments:
        - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

But at the end it does not give me two different instances (checked with `spl_object_hash`)

My question is, do you have any idea how can I get different instances?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `{ name: form.type, alias: shamp_searchable }` tag you basically add an entry in an array of `FormType` that will be passed to the Form component.

Your service is requested only one time from the DIC : when initializing this array. When the Form component needs your `FormType`, it will only retrieve it by alias from this array.

---

Solution you have to create a factory service that create a shamp form type:

```
/**
 * @param ShampSearchableFormTypeFactory $shampFactory
 */
public function __contruct(ShampSearchableFormTypeFactory $shampFactory)
{
    $this->shampFactory = $shampFactory;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('primary', $this->shampFactory->createFormType(), [
            'class'  => '\Udg\CoreBundle\Entity\Ingredients\Ingredient',
           'source' => $this->router->generate('adminIngredient_search'),
        ])
        ->add('secondaries', $this->shampFactory->createFormType(), [
            'class'    => '\Udg\CoreBundle\Entity\Ingredients\Ingredient',
            'source'   => $this->router->generate('adminIngredient_search'),
            'multiple' => true,
        ])
    ...
}
```

---

edited : duplication of tags does not work

Comment: Duplicating alias don't work, the second alias is not found: "Could not load type "shamp_searchable_2"". The good way seems to use form event instead. I'll try factory as a quick fix (no much code to change)

Comment: I've just take a look at the compiler pass that manage form type aliases and it consider that there is only one tag per form :/  I don't see why you would look into form event to obtain the expected result (unless the `secondaries` formtype depends on the `primary` one).